# Script runs fine in debug mode but not runs in run mode in IE Browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have tried following code both in Firefox and IE.
Firefox it is working fine but in IE it is not working . Im using IEv11 ,selenium v2.45 and also i tried with v2.46 and 2.44 .IE Driver Server v2.46. Please help me

```
public class IEBrowser {
    WebDriver driver;
    @Test
    public void url(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "E:\\IEDriverServer.exe");
      driver =  new InternetExplorerDriver();              
     driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
     driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("hi");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code before finding the elements:

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
```

This is applicable to any appium project. *Works in Android Appium too.

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine in my System for all browsers.This may be due to internet speed as well.Any how add a [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) and see

```
  driver.get("http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);//Unit in Seconds
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("firstname"))).sendKeys("hi");
```

Comment: i tried this code but same problem is coming i gave extra time but its not working.My internet speed is too good no problem on my connection . .